# Smallest eigenvalue without inverse

Tags: linear-algebra, eigensystem, eigenvalues, iterative-method

Suppose $A\in\mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$ is a symmetric, positive definite matrix.  $A$ is big enough that it's expensive to solve $Ax=b$ directly.

**Is there an iterative algorithm for finding the smallest eigenvalue of $A$ that doesn't involve inverting $A$ in each iteration?**

That is, I'd have to use an iterative algorithm like conjugate gradients to solve $Ax=b$, so repeatedly applying $A^{-1}$ seems like an expensive "inner loop."  I only need a single eigenvector.

Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried using the Cholesky decomposition? You'd have to factor $A$ into $L L^T$ with $L$ being a triangular matrix. Once you have the factorization (you only do this once) you can use it in every iteration to solve the system very fast by back and forward substitution.

Comment: Is A a sparse matrix?

Comment: $A$ has some block structure, but I'd prefer not to mess with it if I don't have to -- so I was looking into "matrix free methods."  The "LOBPCG" algorithm has some promise, I think!  @Juan, the Cholesky factorization is still quite expensive.

Comment: If you are using matlab or octave use the `eigs`-routine. It is an iterative method. There are options to specify which eigenvalue you want, e.g. _smallest real_.

Comment: I understand and am indeed using eigs in matlab.  But if you specify options like "sm" in eigs, then it requires the inverse of $A$ rather than $A$.  Check out the table in the documentation:  http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/eigs.html

Comment: There is a TraceMIN solver in Trilinos's Anasazi, which is an iterative solver for minimizing $X^TAX$ subject to $X^TX=I$, which gives the smallest eigenvalues: https://trilinos.org/docs/dev/packages/anasazi/doc/html/classAnasazi_1_1Experimental_1_1TraceMin.html

Answer (score 15, accepted):

1. Compute the largest-magnitude eigenvalue $\lambda_{max}$ of $A$ (with, say, `eigs('lm')`).
2. Then compute the largest magnitude (negative) eigenvalue $\hat{\lambda}_{max}$ of $M = A - \lambda_{max}I$ (again, through a standard call to `eigs('lm')`).
3. Observe that $\hat{\lambda}_{max} + \lambda_{\max} = \lambda_{min}(A)$. The reason why this holds is explained [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/271864/power-iteration-smallest-eigenvalue).
4. Find your eigenvector $v$ by solving $(A - \lambda_{min} I) v = 0$.