# scipy.linalg.sparse.eigsh does not work for generalised eigenvalues

Tags: python, eigenvalues, machine-learning

I asked this question over at StackOverflow and someone told me that I'd get a better answer here. So here's my problem:

I'm working on a machine learning project which involves doing a Principal Component Analysis on some labeled data and using those labels to extract more valuable information from the data.

To do that, I'm calculating a scatter matrix for each class, and for each pair of classes I need to solve a generalised eigenvalue problem for their scatter matrices, as follows:

$$S_i  v = w  (S_j + \beta I) v,$$

where $\beta$ is a multiplier and $I$ is the identity matrix. Now, this is the code in python:

```
        jeigenvalues = eigsh(scatter_j, k=10, return_eigenvectors=False, maxiter=100)
        print('eigenvalues made')
        beta = betaMult*mean(jeigenvalues)
        print(beta)
        print(scatter_j+beta*eye(shape(x_data)[1]))
        w, v = eigsh(scatter_i,M=scatter_j+beta*eye(shape(x_data)[1]),k=int(numberOfEVs/45), maxiter=100)
        print(i,j,'done')
```

`numberOfEVs` is 90 in my current code (so that it's divisible by 45).

But the problem is, at the line where I use the `eigsh` for the aforementioned formula, it never gives me an answer. It keeps eating more and more memory without even completing a single iteration (I set its `maxiter` input to 1, and it still didn't give an answer). When I don't give the `eigsh` function the `M` argument (which is the matrix on the right side of the generalised EV problem and it is assumed to be "I" when not specified), it works correctly. But when `M` is provided, it becomes unresponsive.

Any ideas?

EDIT: The scatter matrices have rather small entries, mostly around 10^-5. I've also tried multiplying the left hand side by the inverse of the RHS matrix, and again it's having the same issue (goes on for a long time without an answer). Is the smallness of these entries the issue? How can I solve it, then?

Comment: Welcome to SciComp.SE! How large are your matrices $S_i$? Are they indeed sparse and symmetric? For a generalized eigenvalue problem, the matrix `M` must be symmetric and positive definite. Maybe your shift $\beta$ is not large enough if $S_j$ is not s.p.d.?

Comment: The algorithm behind `eigsh` uses implicitly restarted Arnoldi for the standard eigenvalue problem $M^{-1}Ax = \lambda x$, i.e., it requires the solution of $Mx = y$ in every iteration. For this, `eigsh` computes an LU factorization of $M$, which is probably what's taking so long. You might get better performance (or at least an idea what's going wrong) by precomputing such a factorization and passing a function that uses this factorization to solve the system as the `Minv` argument.

Comment: Thank you!
The matrices are scatter matrices, so they're both symmetric and positive definite. I'll try out the solution you told me, but I also tried the inv function (for sparse) and that too displayed the same kind of behaviour.
I've tried changing beta (it's been both ~0.001 and ~0.00001, with the same behaviour from the eigsh function).

Comment: `inv` is never a good idea for sparse matrices. Your range of $\beta$ might still be too small. You could try to compute the smallest eigenvalue of $S_j$ (e.g., using [this trick](http://scicomp.stackexchange.com/q/21733/1804)) to see how large of a shift you need.

Comment: Thank you for your advice. Increasing beta finally worked: the algorithm takes ~25 minutes for each eigsh and takes a couple of GBs of memory, but it finally gives an answer.

Comment: If I were approaching the general problem, I might look at sweeping k-means and comparing how the data itself "says" it wants to be clustered against the labels.  The (often unstated) presumption in principal components is that the data is decently approximated by a hyper-ellipsoid.  In practice, that's not always true.  Think of the [pathological cases for clustering](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/133656/how-to-understand-the-drawbacks-of-k-means).