# Zero Eigenvalues in Lanczos Algorithm

Tags: linear-algebra, python, eigenvalues, quantum-mechanics

I need to find the smallest few eigenvalues of a Hamiltonian ([*exact* diagonalization](https://en.wikiversity.org/wiki/Quantum_Simulation/Exact_diagonalization)) I use Python, and SciPy's built-in sparse eigenvalue solver. I notice, however, that for my small system (only a 40k x 40k matrix) the program takes hours, maybe even days. I began to suspect something was up.

One thing I note is that my matrix should have a zero eigenvalue. Will that cause havoc in the eigenvalue solvers? If so, what is the way to remedy this?

Comment: 40k is *huge* for trying to find all eigenvalues. Sparse eigenvalue solvers are built to get a few selected eigenvalues effectively, not all of them. A zero eigenvalue doesn't affect this, though. (Side note: Make sure you have a decent optimized BLAS installed. The difference between scipy linked against a stock BLAS and, say, OpenBLAS is staggering.)

Comment: Want to write the equations for your system? What is the potential?

Comment: @ChristianClason I do only seek out the smallest eigenvalues. Sorry if that wasn't explicit enough. I fixed it.

Comment: @nicoguaro It's not a Schrodinger-like equation where $H=T+V$, rather, it's in second quantized form and is not quadratic, meaning the size of the Hilbert space scales as $2^N$. Not sure if it'll be too helpful.

Comment: Dirac's equation-like? There should be a form you write your problem down

Answer (score 4):

The [SciPy tutorial](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/tutorial/arpack.html) explicitly states

> Note that ARPACK is generally better at finding extremal eigenvalues: that is, eigenvalues with large magnitudes. In particular, using `which = 'SM'` may lead to slow execution time and/or anomalous results. A better approach is to use shift-invert mode.

and goes on to describe that. Basically, if $\lambda$ is the smallest by magnitude eigenvalue of $A$, then 
$\nu = \frac{1}{\lambda}$
is the *largest* by magnitude eigenvalue of $A^{-1}$. (With the same trick, you can get the eigenvalue closest to a given $\sigma$ by looking at the largest for $(A-\sigma I)^{-1}$.) Hence, to compute, say, the three smallest by magnitude eigenvalues, you can instead use

```
eigenval, eigenvec = eigsh(A, 3, sigma=0, which='LM')
```

If you already know that $A$ has a zero eigenvalue and is therefore not invertible (and you have some idea where the next closest are), you can instead use a nonzero shift, e.g., `sigma=0.01` to shift your matrix away from singular. If `sigma` is small enough, that should still get you the ones closest to zero.

(Also, as noted in my comment, make sure you have a proper optimized BLAS such as OpenBLAS installed -- for sparse eigenvalues, SciPy calls ARPACK (written in Fortran) which in turn makes heavy use of BLAS.)

**EDIT:** If it's the smallest *algebraic* eigenvalue you're after, you can use [this neat trick](https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/a/21742/1804): If you have an estimate $\sigma$ of the largest eigenvalue (say, by computing it using `which='LM'`), you can use that to shift all eigenvalues to be negative -- so that the smallest algebraic eigenvalues are also the largest magnitude ones. Then simply use `which='LM'` on $A-\sigma I$ and shift back.

Comment: Nice, I agree. I am more interested in the smallest algebraic values, though (which = 'SA') since it's a quantum problem, and we almost always are most interested in the lowest-lying states.

Comment: Also, I took your advice and linked up numpy and scipy with OpenBLAS. You're right, I'm actually seeing the program finish!

Answer (score 3):

While the smallest eigenvalues of a sparse 40k x 40k matrix might be obtained in a reasonable amount of time using ARPACK and some handy tricks through the SciPy wrapper, as mentioned here, the problem will scale at best as $N^2$.

For any larger eigenvalue problems I almost always recommend [SLEPc](http://slepc.upv.es/), which also has a Python wrapper (through perhaps not as natural as the C versions) and in many cases calls parallel versions of the routines SciPy would.